# Is there a way to use one fragment in landscape and others in portrait when using NavController?

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using the barcode scanner on one of my fragments and I need to rotate just that fragment to scan the barcode. I tried rotate by OnDestinationChangedListener in my single activity, but it seems to be so costly. How I can do this in a better way?

Comment: See https://github.com/square/flow/blob/1656288d1cb4a92dfbcff8276f4d7f9e3390419b/flow-sample-orientation-lock/src/main/java/flow/sample/orientation/OrientationSampleDispatcher.java#L99-L107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can Simply apply The Fragment Flags when you navigate to fragment Like This

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  activity?.let {
    it.window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
    it.window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
   }
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
     activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
}
```

Comment: Nice! That onCreate() overriding is relevant to rotation?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement ViewModel to handle screen rotation cases

below links may help you

https://android.jlelse.eu/dive-deep-into-androids-viewmodel-android-architecture-components-e0a7ded26f70

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel